# I'm trying to get Java to ask the user for the number of jobs they've had and the names of those jobs

Tags: java

I want the user to be able to input a number of jobs and then input the name of each job. Right now I'm kind of brute forcing it with if else statements

```
System.out.println("How many jobs have you had?");
int numberjobs = scanner.nextInt();

if (numberjobs == 3) {
    System.out.println("What was your first job?");
    scanner.nextLine();
    company1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What was your second job?");
    company2 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What was your third job?");
    company3 = scanner.nextLine();
} else if (numberjobs == 2) {
    System.out.println("What was your first job?");
    scanner.nextLine();
    company1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What was your second job?");
    company2 = scanner.nextLine();
} else if (numberjobs == 1) {
    System.out.println("What was your first job?");
    scanner.nextLine();
    company1 = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Is there a way to make a loop more easily? Can I make a loop with no upper limit to the number of jobs inputted?

Comment: Use an array and a loop.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of companies, and then populate it using a loop:

```
List<String> companies = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("How many jobs have you had?");
int numberjobs = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i=0; i < numberjobs; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Enter job " + i + " please:");
    String company = scanner.nextLine();
    companies.add(company);
}
```

We could have also used an array here, but `List` is more flexible should the logic in your program require adding more jobs later on at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use loops:

```
System.out.println("How many jobs have you had?");
int numberjobs = scanner.nextInt();

String companies[] = new String[numberjobs];

for(int i=0; i<numberjobs; i++) {
    System.out.println("What was your job #" + (i+1) + "?");
    company[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```